# word search in python :a search which return the indices the letters

Tags: python, list, index-error

#the following program checks the words in a 2D array and returns a nested list of the indices of the words.the algorithm checks the words in horizontal direction(left &right),vertical direction (upward and downward) and diagonally(left to right in the downward direction)
**problem that i'am facing **
#the program returns correct indices for some of the words but for some it returns none.for some words the program crashes giving an index error(list index out of range)
**code**

```
 def find(word):
   new_list=[]
   
   

   print("lenght",len(word))
   for i in range(3):
      for j in range(3):
         
        if board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i][j+1]==word[1] and board[i][j+2]==word[2]:#horizontal(right)
            
            x=i
            z=j
            
            
            for k in range(len(word)):
               #print('valuw of ',k)
               if board[x][z]==word[k]:
                  
                  
                  new_list.append(x)
                  new_list.append(z)
                  print(new_list)
                  z+=1
                  
                  if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                     print(new_list) 
                     return new_list #returns nested list
        
        elif  board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i+1][j]==word[1] and board[i+2][j]==word[2]: vertical(downward)
            
            u=i
            v=j
            
            
            for k in range(len(word)):
            #print('valuw of ',k)
                if board[u][v]==word[k]:
                  
                  
                    new_list.append(u)
                    new_list.append(v)
                    print(new_list)
                    u+=1
                  
                    if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                        print(new_list) 
                        return new_list
            
        elif board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i+1][j+1]==word[1] and board[i+2][j+2]==word[2]: #diagonal
            
            a=i
            b=j
            
            
            for k in range(len(word)):
               #print('valuw of ',k)
                if board[a][b]==word[k]:
                  
                  
                    new_list.append(a)
                    new_list.append(b)
                    print(new_list)
                    a+=1
                    b+=1
                    if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                        print(new_list) 
                        return new_list                      
        elif board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i][j-1]==word[1] and board[i][j-2]==word[2]: #horizontal(left)
            
            c=i
            d=j
            
            
            for k in range(len(word)):
               #print('valuw of ',k)
                if board[c][d]==word[k]:
                  
                  
                    new_list.append(c)
                    new_list.append(d)
                    print(new_list)
                    
                    d-=1
                    if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                        print(new_list) 
                        return new_list
        elif board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i-1][j]==word[1] and board[i-2][j]==word[2]: #verical(upward)
            
            f=i
            g=j
            
            
            for k in range(len(word)):
               #print('valuw of ',k)
                if board[c][d]==word[k]:
                  
                  
                    new_list.append(f)
                    new_list.append(g)
                    print(new_list)
                    
                    f-=1
                    if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                        print(new_list) 
                        return new_list
board=[['p','o','t'],
        ['x','y','z'],
        ['a','p','o']]          
               
         

output=[]
l=['pot','pyo','ozt']
for word in l:
    
    output.append(find(word))
print(output)#print the nested list containing the indices enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that the indices are actually valid for the array. If you have a 3x3 array and i=2,j=2, then j+1 will be off the board and Python will give you an IndexError. You have to be even more careful with negative indices as those will not give an error as board[-1][-1] is the same as board[2][2].

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things that can go wrong with this code.

1. List index out of range:

   You are doing a nested `for` loop with the rows and columns of the given board without ever checking if you're accessing a valid index in your board. There are certain areas in your code where you do `i+1` and `i+2` similarly with `j`. These can certainly go outside of the scope of your board.
2. Function returns None:

   You are not handling the `else` case in your nested `for` loop. In python if your function does not reach a return statement it automatically returns None type. Your function returns None in cases where it hasn't reached any of the `return new_list` statements.

Check this code out where I've added a new function which checks if you're accessing a valid position in the board.

```
def is_valid_position(i,j):
    return True if i<len(board) and j<len(board[0]) else False

def find(word):
    new_list = []
    print("length", len(word))
    
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if is_valid_position(i,j) and is_valid_position(i,j+1) and is_valid_position(i,j+2):
                if board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i][j+1]==word[1] and board[i][j+2]==word[2]:
                    x=i
                    z=j
                    for k in range(len(word)):
                        if board[x][z]==word[k]:
                            new_list.append(x)
                            new_list.append(z)
                            print(new_list)
                            z+=1
                    
                            if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                                print(new_list) 
                                return new_list
            if is_valid_position(i,j) and is_valid_position(i+1,j) and is_valid_position(i+2,j):
                if board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i+1][j]==word[1] and board[i+2][j]==word[2]:  
                    u=i
                    v=j
                    for k in range(len(word)):
                        if board[u][v]==word[k]:
                            new_list.append(u)
                            new_list.append(v)
                            print(new_list)
                            u+=1
                            if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                                print(new_list) 
                                return new_list
            if is_valid_position(i,j) and is_valid_position(i+1,j+1) and is_valid_position(i+2,j+2):
                if board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i+1][j+1]==word[1] and board[i+2][j+2]==word[2]:
                    a=i
                    b=j
                    for k in range(len(word)):
                        if board[a][b]==word[k]:
                            new_list.append(a)
                            new_list.append(b)
                            print(new_list)
                            a+=1
                            b+=1
                            if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                                print(new_list)
                                return new_list
            if is_valid_position(i,j) and is_valid_position(i,j-1) and is_valid_position(i,j-2):
                if board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i][j-1]==word[1] and board[i][j-2]==word[2]:
                    c=i
                    d=j
                    for k in range(len(word)):
                        if board[c][d]==word[k]:
                            new_list.append(c)
                            new_list.append(d)
                            print(new_list)
                            d-=1
                            if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                                print(new_list)
                                return new_list
            if is_valid_position(i,j) and is_valid_position(i-1,j) and is_valid_position(i-2,j):
                if board[i][j]==word[0] and board[i-1][j]==word[1] and board[i-2][j]==word[2]:
                    f=i
                    g=j
                    for k in range(len(word)):
                        if board[f][g]==word[k]:
                            new_list.append(f)
                            new_list.append(g)
                            print(new_list)
                            f-=1
                            if len(new_list) ==len(word)*2:
                                print(new_list)
                                return new_list
                        
board=[['p','o','t'],
        ['x','y','z'],
        ['a','p','o']]          
               
         

output=[]
l=['pot','pyo','ozt']
for word in l:
    output.extend(find(word))
print(output)
```

This above code gives an output as follows

```
length 3
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2]
length 3
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
length 3
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2]
```